# Debian/linux dependency error

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I am trying to install mysql-server on debian linux server, but i get this:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhDrW.png)

I have tried almost everything I found when i googled my problem, nothing worked.
This problem happens with other packages too, not only mysql-server(for example mysql-client).

I tried apt-get install -f and all the other possible fixes from the terminal and nothing worked.
Please note I don't have good experience working with linux.

This is what i get from apt-get update:

[the error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUevy.png)

Thank you.

Comment: A) Screenshots are really, **really** annoying, especially as external links. B) Stack Overflow is for questions specific to coding, not server administration. Have a look over at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) if you're having infrastructure and OS problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your problem is related to your repository list `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I believe you don't have all the necessary repositories listed there. I suggest changing your sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list` to something like the following:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

After that run `apt-get update` and try the install and fixings (such as `apt-get install -f`) again.

Comment: thank you so much, i spent at least 3 hours looking for a solution.